# Is there any error in my aws Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backend

Can any one just tell me what's wrong with the below code.
I am getting a timeout error for this function. even though i increase the timme in aws basic settings timeout it shows the same.
from decrypting.js i am decrypting the value and using that in index.js `await decryptSecret("S3_SECRET")`.
Is this the proper way?
can anyone help me with the best solution for this issue

**index.js**

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")
const { decryptSecret } = require('decrypting.js');


exports.handler = function () {
    try {
        const directoryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, process.env.LocalPath);

        fs.readdir(directoryPath, async function (error, files) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error getting directory information");
            } else {
                console.log("Loading lambda Function...")
                let cloudStorageFiles = [];
                aws.config.setPromisesDependency();
                aws.config.update({
                    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
                    secretAccessKey: await decryptSecret("S3_SECRET"),
                    // process.env.S3_SECRET,
                    region: process.env.S3_REGION
                })
                const s3 = new aws.S3();
                const response = await s3.listObjectsV2({
                    Bucket: 'xxxxx',
                    Prefix: 'xxxxx'
                }, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err, err.stack);
                    } else {
                        var contents = data.Contents;
                        contents.forEach((content) => {
                            cloudStorageFiles.push(content.Key);
                        });
                    }
                }).promise();
                console.log('First-Cloud-File-Storage:', cloudStorageFiles)
                // return cloudStorageFiles
 };
            console.log("Lambda function ended")
        });
        // return `Lambda function successfully completed`
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Ooops...Error!", error)
    };
};
```

**decrypting.js**

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const kms = new aws.KMS();

const decrypted = {};

exports.decryptSecret = async function (secretName) {
    if (decrypted[secretName]) {
        console.log('returning cached secret-name:' + secretName);
        return decrypted[secretName]
    }
    console.log('decrypting:' + secretName);
    try {
        const req = { CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(process.env[secretName], 'base64') };
        const data = await kms.decrypt(req).promise();
        const decryptedVal = data.Plaintext.toString('ascii');
        decrypted[secretName] = decryptedVal;
        console.log('decryptedVal:', decryptedVal)
        return decryptedVal;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('decrypt error:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

**Error Message:**

{
"errorMessage": "2021-02-10T06:48:52.723Z 5dec4413-f8db-49bd-8075-661ccf6ef1a4 Task timed out after 50.02 seconds"
}

**loged output:**
INFO    Loading lambda Function...
INFO    decryptingS3_SECRET

Comment: Is the function in a VPC?

Comment: Yes this function is at VPC @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Your function is timing out because it does not have access to the internet. Since it is running inside of a VPC, it [must be placed in a private subnet to have outbound internet access](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/). This includes S3.

A private subnet in this case is a subnet where the default route (`0.0.0.0/0`) points to a NAT gateway and not an internet gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Your function times out, because a Lambda function associated with a VPC has **no internet access** by default. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet):

> When you connect a function to a VPC in your account, the function **can't access the internet** unless your VPC provides access.

Subsequently, your function **can't connect** to the public endpoints of the S3 and KMS. To rectify this, there are **two options**:

- place your function in **private subnet** (public will not work), setup **NAT** gateway in a public subnet and configure route tables so that your function can access internet using NAT. The process is explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/).
- setup [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) for KMS and S3. This will allow your function to **privately** access these services without the need for internet access.

Comment: If it is an VPC no internet access issue.without using decrypting.js file if i run my index.js file it is working correctly(without decryption i will get data from environment file).Can you tell me what are the steps i need to check exactly.

Comment: @sai You have to check the links I provided and decide if you want to use NAT or VPC endpoint to access KMS.

Comment: Okay let me try with VPC endpoint for access@Marchin